# How do I map part of an object model to an XML column in Entity Framework and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, entity-framework

I am quite new to Entity Framework, and I am trying to work out a somewhat complex mapping. Here are my objects:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Description {get;set;}
    public virtual Child Child {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Description {get;set;}
}
```

And here is the database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [Parent](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY,
[Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Child] [xml] NULL
```

So the Child column on the Parent tables contains a serialised version of the Child object. It needs to be updated when the Parent object is saved if the Child object is changed. It is not yet essential for it to be lazy loaded but could be in the future.

I know this is possible with NHibernate using IUserType but I haven't figured out how to do it yet with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it is for the Parent object to have an XmlData fields. Then, in my class that overrides DbContext, I overrided the following methods and handled the following events:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public ObjectContext ObjectContext
    {
        get { return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext; }
    }

    private void InterceptBefore(ObjectStateEntry item)
    {
        var parent = item.Entity as Parent;

        if (parent!= null)
            parent.XmlData = XmlObjectSerializer.Serialize(applicationForm.Child);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        const EntityState entitiesToTrack = EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted;

        var elementsToSave =
            this.ObjectContext
                .ObjectStateManager
                .GetObjectStateEntries(entitiesToTrack)
                .ToList();

        elementsToSave.ForEach(InterceptBefore);
        var result = base.SaveChanges();
        return result;
    }

    public void ObjectContext_ObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = e.Entity as Parent;

        if (parent != null)
            parent.Child = XmlObjectSerializer.Deserialize<Child>(applicationForm.XmlData);
    }
}
```